# Plotting fault lines without connecting every line together

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have two lists of latitudes and longitudes representing a bunch of points making up geologic faults. I'm trying to make a map (through Basemap) showing these faults as lines, however, using the pyplot.plot function, these points will connect faults that are miles apart and I don't want that.

[image: plot showing faults along a map connected by lines]
So far what I have been doing is just making the points rather big so that it just looks like they're a bunch of lines, but when I zoom in it is clearly points and not a line.

[image: plot showing fault lines as many points, making it look like lines]

It may also be useful to know that these points that make up a single fault are separated by 50 meters. Initially I had a code where I determined the distance between these points using the great circle tool and created a new list of distances:

```
f_distance = []
c = 0
for i,j in zip(fault_lat,fault_lon):
    while c < (len(fault_lon)-1):
        location1 = (fault_lat[c],fault_lon[c])
        location2 = (fault_lat[c+1],fault_lon[c+1])
        distance = great_circle(location1,location2).meters
        f_distance.append(distance)
        c+=1
```

then if that distance was less than or equal to 50, it would plot them and (hopefully) plot the line between them, otherwise it would skip it.

```
c = 0
for i,j,k in zip(map_q_fault_lon,map_q_fault_lat,q_fault_distance):
    if k <= 50:
         map.plot(i,j,linestyle = '-',linewidth = 1.00,color = 'black')
    c+=1
```

But sadly it just gave me a blank screen. Is there anyway I could rework this so that it will do what I'm asking for?

Comment: In your for loop, your `i,j` is a single point so you need atleast 2 points for a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, you just need to pass both the *current* point and the *previous* or *next* point to `plot()`. If you change your filtering loop to something more like

```py
for ii in range(len(map_q_fault_lon)):
    if q_fault_distance[ii] <= 50 and ii > 0:
        map.plot(map_q_fault_lon[ii-1:ii+1], map_q_fault_lat[ii-1:ii+1], 'k-', lw=1.0)
```

you should see the desired filtering. Here is the result of this method with some generated data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For distances ~50m, you really don't need great circle distance for a good approximation. I'll assume that `fault_lat` and `fault_lon` are numpy arrays in radians. If not, convert them:

```
fault_lat = np.radians(fault_lat)
fault_lon = np.radians(fault_lon)
```

Now you can compute distances using a simple formula involving the radius of the Earth and appropriate scaling for latitude:

```
 r = 6378000
 dist = r * np.sqrt(np.diff(fault_lat)**2 + (np.diff(fault_lon) * np.cos(0.5 * (fault_lat[1:] + fault_lat[:-1])))**2)
```

This creates an index of (approximate) distances between successive points. You can split the result on locations where the distance exceeds some threshold like 50m:

```
threshold = 50
indices = np.flatnonzero(dist > threshold) + 1
lat_segments = np.split(fault_lat, indices)
lon_segments = np.split(fault_lon, indices)
```

You can plot the result with:

```
for lat, lon in zip(lat_segments, lon_segments):
    map.plot(lon, lat)
```